# useState array is undefined even though it is initialized as empty array

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, react-hooks

I'm working in a React Native Expo project with Firebase v9 and I'm getting an error because of my state variabel categories(I think that's the issue).
This component allows the user to add categories to a flatlist, which is seen here:

[image]

As it shows i'm already getting an warning which says: '[Unhandled promise rejection: FirebaseError: Function setDoc() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field categories in document users/Hk4k6fKrtZZG1BGffFrOTRvuT2h2)]'

And when i add a category i get the error -> Render error: undefined is not an object(evaluating 'iter[symbol.iterator]')

This is the code for my CategoryComponent:

```
import { StyleSheet, View, FlatList, Alert, Animated} from 'react-native'
import React, { useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import { db, } from '../../firebase/firebase'
import { doc, setDoc, onSnapshot} from 'firebase/firestore';
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import { Button, Divider, Subheading, Text, Modal, Portal, TextInput } from 'react-native-paper';
import Swipeable from 'react-native-gesture-handler/Swipeable'
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';


export default function CategoryComponent() {
  const containerStyle = {backgroundColor: 'white', padding: 100, margin: 10};
  const [textInput, setTextInput] = useState('');
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState([])
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const [dataFetch, setDataFetch] = useState(false);


  useEffect(
    () => 
      onSnapshot(doc(db, "users", `${firebase.auth().currentUser.uid}`), (doc) => {
        setCategories(doc.data().categories)
        setDataFetch(true)
      }
      ),
      console.log(categories),
    []
  );


  useEffect(() => {
    addToFirebase();
  }, [categories])


  const showModal = () => {
    setVisible(true);
  }
  

  const hideModal = () => {
    setVisible(false);
  }


  const categoryNavigate = (item) => {
    navigation.navigate("Your Organizer tasks", {item});
  }


  const addCategory = (textInput) => {
    setCategories((prevState) => {
      return [
        {name: textInput, id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + 1 },
        ...prevState
      ];
    })

    hideModal();
  }


  const addToFirebase = async() => {
    if(dataFetch) {
      await setDoc(doc(db, "users", `${firebase.auth().currentUser.uid}`), {
        categories: categories
      }, {merge: true});
    }
  };

  
  const deleteItem = (item) => {
    setCategories((prevState) => {
      return prevState.filter(category => category.id != item.id)
    })        
  }


  const DataComponent = (item) => {
    const rightSwipe = (progress, dragX) => {
      const scale = dragX.interpolate({
        inputRange: [-100, 0],
        outputRange: [1, 0],
        extrapolate: 'clamp'
      });

      return(
        <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.8} onPress={() => deleteItem(item)}>
          <View>
            <Animated.Text style={[styles.deleteItem, {transform: [{scale}]}]}>Delete</Animated.Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )
    }

    return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => categoryNavigate(item)}>
      <Swipeable renderRightActions={rightSwipe}>
        <View>
          <Text>{item.name}</Text>
        </View>
      </Swipeable>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }


  return (
    <View>
      <Subheading>Your categories</Subheading>
        <View>
          <FlatList
          style={styles.flatList}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
          data={categories}
          renderItem={ ({item}) => (
            <DataComponent {...item}/>
            )}
            />
        </View>

      <View>
        <Button mode="contained" uppercase={false} onPress={showModal}>
          Add a category
        </Button>
      </View>
      <Portal>
        <Modal visible={visible} onDismiss={hideModal} contentContainerStyle={containerStyle}>
          <Text>Name your category: </Text>
          <TextInput placeholder="Enter category name" value={textInput} onChangeText={val => setTextInput(val)}/>
          <Button mode="contained" uppercase={false} onPress={() => addCategory(textInput)}>
            Add
          </Button>
        </Modal>
      </Portal>
    </View>
  )
}
```

I have consol.logged the state variable categories in my useEffect and i don't understand why it shows ''undefined'' when I have initialized it as an empty array, so i would expect to see a empty array in the consol.log for the state variable categories when there is no categories in the flatlist.

Comment: can you console.log(categories)?

Comment: I have done it, and it says its undefined for categories

Comment: If your categories are undefined then obviously it will throw error

Comment: You can't merge or add a value which is undefined

Comment: Yes i know that, and i also now it is the error, but i don't get it why it is undefined, when i have initialized it as an empty array.

Comment: Because the consol.log is in a useEffect, it will log it multiple times, so it shows first: Array[] and then undefined immediately undefined.

Comment: can you console.log(doc.data().categories) ?

Comment: Actually no, it also says undefined, do you think an if(doc.exists) statement could resolve it?

Comment: No I don't think so It will work

Comment: does data correspond to the firebase.auth().currentUser.uid (current user) exists or not in firestore ?

Comment: Yes, when i only consol.log(doc.data()) it shows the correct data for the current user logged in.

Comment: can you show me the output quickly?

Comment: please do quickly

Comment: Yes ofc and sorry, i have posted the output as an answer,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you clearly look there is no such category type key value in the object, so when you perform setCategories(doc.data().categories) it sets the **categories value undefined** .You can't merge or add a Doc where the field value is undefined.